# Filter consecutive identical characters using Sed and Grep

Tags: grep, sed

How to find the occurrences of three consecutive and identical word characters, for example  "aaa", "bbb" etc using  `sed` and `grep`?

I meant to find out words which have length 3 and are made from repeating characters, i.e. all characters of word must be same.

Comment: Should more occurences be reported? Such as `aaaa`

Comment: No just 3 occurrence.

Comment: And of course you mean any word character, i.e. you don't want to explicitly input the characters to look for, right?

Comment: I meant to find out words which hav length 3 and are made from repeating characters.,ie all characters of word must be same.

Comment: Eg aaa bbb rrr etc.  I need to filter out such words from a file.

Comment: Ok got it, last question, which characters should be matched? I guess both upper-case and lower-case alphabetical characters?

Comment: Yes both uppercase and lowercase. But it aaa and AAA is different. I mean aAa is not the word which should be filtered. But if u can develop even for this. Please post this also.

Comment: Done, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/\(^\| \)\([A-Za-z]\)\2\2\($\| \)/p' file
```

Using `grep`:

```
grep '\(^\| \)\([A-Za-z]\)\2\2\($\| \)' file
```

- `\(^\| \)`: matches either the start of the line or a  character;
- `\([A-Za-z]\)`: matches and groups any upper-case or lower-case alphabetical character;
- `\2`: matches the previously grouped character;
- `\2`: matches the previously grouped character;
- `\($\| \)`: matches either the end of the line or a  character;

```
~$ cat file
aa word word
word wordaaaword word
aAa word word
aaa word word
word bbb word
word word ccc
aaaa word word
~$ sed -n '/\(^\| \)\([A-Za-z]\)\2\2\($\| \)/p' file
aaa word word
word bbb word
word word ccc
~$ grep '\(^\| \)\([A-Za-z]\)\2\2\($\| \)' file
aaa word word
word bbb word
word word ccc
```

Comment: Thanks worked. But If I have multiple such words in line. Then??

Comment: @user2280915 It's the same, because a single match within the line is enough to print it. Just try it with an `aaa aaa` line

Comment: Yeah worked perfectly. There is some glitch with grep.  Just add * after space.  (^| *)

Comment: @user2280915 If you want to match multiple spaces, use `\+` instead of `*`, because `*` will match even 0 spaces, i.e. it will match an `aaa` string after any character, meaning you'll get also line containing words with say `aaa` at the end of the word (such as `aaaa` or `nottobematchedaaa`)

Comment: No it will not because I first given space then used * this will going to work as +. It's like gg*. It will now check for atleast 1 g not 0 g.

Comment: @user2280915 No, it won't. `*` makes *the immediately preceding character or grouped pattern* match 0 or more times; `\+` makes the the immediately preceding character or grouped pattern match 1 or more times; you are confusing it with doing something like `aa*`, which will match the character `a` 1 or more times in basic regular expression, which don't have the `+` quantifier; if you dont trust me, try it on the example file in my answer: it will match also the `aaaa word word` line.

Comment: I misinterpreted. But I was trying gg* which is equivalent to g+. But m not sure why grep is not matching words like aaa bbb ccc ie these words follow each other immediately. But grep leave bbb and show aaa & ccc. M able to tell this because all matched pattern appears red.                                                         M new to this so sorry for some silly mistakes and silly questions

Comment: @user2280915 I don't understand. You tried `grep 'gg*'` and it matched `aaa` and `ccc` in `aaa bbb ccc`?

Comment: No. I was just explaining what I m thinking. Since space character is invisible.  My question is when I used ur formulated grep it matched perfectly. But if a line contains consecutively multiple such patterns ie a single line contains aaa bbb ccc did.  Then above grep formulation gives alternative words ie aaa ccc. M not able to understand y.

Comment: @user2280915 Ah ok, I've got it. Yes it does, because the pattern has to match completely, so the first match will be `^aaa ` (mind the space at the end!), and `bbb` won't match, because in order to match it would need a leading space, which is not present because the space after `^aaa` has been consumed already in order to match `aaa`; on the other hand, `ccc` has a leading space, since `bbb` hasn't been matched (and neither had its trailing space), and it will match; all of this repeatedly, leading to the "alternated matches pattern"

Comment: I got it :).  Finally

Comment: I have another question if u don't mind

Comment: I was replacing "<B>" &  "</B>" with '<STRONG>' &  '</STRONG >' in a file. It's somewhat like replacing hmtl tags.  I used **sed 's/\<B\>/STRONG /'**. It did the job but if in file [B]  and [/B]  is present. Then also they are changed into  [STRONG]  &  [/STRONG]. I don't get the logic behind it.

Comment: @user2280915 [Ask another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and drop me a comment; make sure you post a sample of the input, a sample of the wrong output and a sample of how you'd like the output to be, so that it's clear exactly what's wrong

Comment: cool! (+1) for the solution and for the courage of confronting all the details.

Answer (score 1):

In a situation like this I prefer annotation (sorry to change the question! ☺)

Instead of finding, this version *marks* the pattern with "".

```
sed -r 's/(\w)\1\1/"&"/g; 
        s/"(..(\w))"\2/\2\1/g'
```

- `s/(\w)\1\1/"&"/g;`  substitutes `...aaa` => `..."aaa"`
- `s/"(..(\w))"\2/\2\1/g` fixes more than 3 chars `..."aaa"a` => `aaaa`

example:

```
aa word wordaaaword word aAa word aaa word
word bbb word word ccc aaaa word word
```

outputs

```
aa word word"aaa"word word aAa word "aaa" word
word "bbb" word word "ccc" aaaa word word
```

**Update** (to cope with the new requirements in the question):

```
sed -r 's/\<(\w)\1\1\>/"&"/g' ex1
```

output:

```
aa word wordaaaword word aAa word "aaa" word
word "bbb" word word "ccc" aaaa word word
```

Comment: @kos, If I see it correctly, this ends up being  simpler than the previous.

Comment: Well yes, there's no need to cope for sequences of the same character longer than 3. A single command and you're set :)